# Transform same column row data with multiple columns data to new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a LARGE pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
"name" "price" "quantity"
"s1"   2       5
"s2"   3       7
"s3"   9       2
"s1"   5       10
"s2"   8       1
etc    etc     etc
```

I want to make a new dataframe which looks like this:

```
"name" "price" "quantity"
"s1"   [2, 5]  [5, 10]
"s2"   [3, 8]  [7, 1]
etc    etc     etc
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this? You shouldn't store lists in a dataframe

Comment: What should I do then? I'm new to pandas and I'm trying to learn =)

Comment: I think the format you have it stored in now is perfectly reasonable.  Much easier to access and query for sure.

Comment: So you think I should keep it as it is right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.groupby` with lambda function for the aggregation:

```
df.groupby('"name"').agg(lambda x: tuple(x))
```

Output:

```
        "price" "quantity"
"name"                   
"s1"    (2, 5)    (5, 10)
"s2"    (3, 8)     (7, 1)
"s3"      (9,)       (2,)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much for that quick answer! You don't know how much I have looked for this lol, thanks again!

Comment: no problem, glad I could help

Comment: `df.groupby('"name"').agg(tuple)`

Comment: I get valueError when I try the df.groupby('"name"').agg(tuple) command, "no results". Do I do something wrong?

Comment: hmm double check that you're using the right column name, they usualy don't have quotes on them (if your column name is *name* then `df.groupby('name')`

Comment: I can't get it to work. Anyways, the old solution worked well, so I think I go for that one. Thanks and have a nice night! =)

Comment: well that's useful feedback, on my end it works. Maybe it's a versioning issue. gn :)